# Records that I query in console from Amplify Datastore are different then the ones in Amplify Content

Tags: react-native, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm new to AWS and React Native and I'm trying to create an aplication that will use AWS Datastore as database to store data. Right now i have this in my App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
import Navigation from './src/navigation'
import { Amplify, DataStore } from "aws-amplify"
import awsmobile from './src/aws-exports'
import { Bdetails } from './src/models';

Amplify.configure(awsmobile)

const bdetailsQuery = async () => {
  const posts = await DataStore.query(Bdetails);
  return posts;
};

const deleteAllBdetails = async () => {
  try {
    const allBdetails = await DataStore.query(Bdetails);

    await Promise.all(allBdetails.map(async (bdetail) => {
      await DataStore.delete(Bdetails, bdetail.id);
    }));

    console.log('All records were deleted.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error when trying to delete records:', error);
  }
};

const createBdetails = async () => {
  try {
    const newBdetails = {
      name: 'Business name',
      city: 'city',
      region: 'region',
      country: 'country',
      address: 'address',
      category: 'category',
      subcategory: 'subcategory',
      latitude: 0.0, 
      longitude: 0.0, 
      image: 'https://example.com/image.jpg' 
    };

    const createdBdetails = await DataStore.save(new Bdetails(newBdetails));

    console.log('Record succesfully created:', createdBdetails);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error when trying to insert record:', error);
  }
};


const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        await createBdetails();
        //await deleteAllBdetails();
        const result = await bdetailsQuery();
        console.log('Datas', JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.root}>
        <Navigation/>
        </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F9FBFC'
  }
})

export default App
```

After I scan my application with expo and I run it on IOS, application works fine, in console I got next logs:

```
{}
 LOG  [INFO] 14:04.224 Reachability - subscribing to reachability in React Native
 LOG  Record succesfully created: {"_deleted": undefined, "_lastChangedAt": undefined, "_version": undefined, "address": "address", "category": "category", "city": "city", "country": "country", "createdAt": null, "id": "9109499f-31c0-458f-807f-b5c254db581c", "image": "https://example.com/image.jpg", "latitude": 0, "longitude": 0, "name": "Business name", "region": "region", "subcategory": "subcategory", "updatedAt": null}
 LOG  Datas [
  {
    "name": "Business name",
    "city": "city",
    "region": "region",
    "country": "country",
    "address": "address",
    "category": "category",
    "subcategory": "subcategory",
    "latitude": 0,
    "longitude": 0,
    "image": "https://example.com/image.jpg",
    "id": "9109499f-31c0-458f-807f-b5c254db581c",
    "createdAt": null,
    "updatedAt": null
  }
]
 LOG  [INFO] 14:04.338 Reachability - Notifying reachability change true
 LOG  [INFO] 14:04.722 Reachability - subscribing to reachability in React Native
 LOG  [INFO] 14:04.723 Reachability - Notifying reachability change true
 LOG  [INFO] 14:04.737 Reachability - subscribing to reachability in React Native
 LOG  [INFO] 14:04.737 Reachability - Notifying reachability change true
 WARN  [WARN] 14:05.563 DataStore - subscriptionError Connection failed: {"errors":[{"message":"Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field '_version' 
in type 'Bdetails' is undefined @ 'onCreateBdetails/_version'"},{"message":"Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field '_lastChangedAt' in type 'Bdetails' is undefined @ 'onCreateBdetails/_lastChangedAt'"},{"message":"Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field '_deleted' in type 'Bdetails' is undefined @ 'onCreateBdetails/_deleted'"}]}
 WARN  [WARN] 14:05.577 DataStore {"cause": {"error": {"errors": [Array]}, "provider": {"_config": [Object], "awsRealTimeSocket": [WebSocket], "connectionState": "Connecting", "connectionStateMonitor": [ConnectionStateMonitor], "connectionStateMonitorSubscription": [Subscription], "keepAliveAlertTimeoutId": 409, "keepAliveTimeout": 300000, "keepAliveTimeoutId": 408, "promiseArray": [Array], "reconnectionMonitor": [ReconnectionMonitor], "socketStatus": 1, "subscriptionObserverMap": [Map]}}, "errorType": "Unknown", "localModel": null, "message": "Connection failed: {\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field '_version' in type 'Bdetails' is undefined @ 'onCreateBdetails/_version'\"},{\"message\":\"Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field '_lastChangedAt' in type 'Bdetails' is undefined @ 'onCreateBdetails/_lastChangedAt'\"},{\"message\":\"Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field '_deleted' in type 'Bdetails' is undefined @ 'onCreateBdetails/_deleted'\"}]}", "model": "Bdetails", "operation": "Create", "process": "subscribe", "recoverySuggestion": "Ensure app code is up to date, auth directives exist and are correct on each model, and that server-side data has not been invalidated by a schema change. If the problem persists, search for or create an issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues", "remoteModel": null}
```

So from what I see, record is successfully insert in database and I can query it (even if I got that warn).

And here comes my problem, this record that i just insert, shouldn't be visible in AWS Console? I mean, here:

[image]

Is something that I do wrong or I can see the data only in my app if I query it like I just do?